# Anaconda-installation: package for MX-Linux needed

Tags: python, linux, bash, anaconda

since MX-Linux (see http:[www.mxlinux.org](http://www.mxlinux.org)) does not have added Anaconda to MX Repository package all the many many folks on MX-linux (which is ranked as #1 Linux ( cf. http://www.distrowatch.com ) for years now - all the folks out there do hot have a good anaconda-support. Thats a sad sad story. Can you do anything and help the community.

the only option left - the hacky-solution: The Arch PKGBUILD has some links for the installer that they use to provide the source: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/?h=anaconda

They say it’s open source, we need that to package it, unless we just provide a routine to the installer.
The Tree section shows us list of links like this, with the code behind each link

```
Mode Name Size
-rw-r--r-- .SRCINFO 627 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r-- .gitignore 43 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r-- PKGBUILD 1233 logstatsplain
-rw-r--r-- anaconda.install 219 logstatsplain
```

but honestly - i have never been doing installation based only on files - always
untill we have some support to the repo-manager of the mx-linux community there is lack of a good method on installing Anaconda on MX-Linux.

remember - the mx-group is ranked as #1 Linux at distrowatch for years now.

btw: there is a solution for debianbased linux-systems: https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/01-Orientation/01.05-Installing-Anaconda-on-Linux/

> 4. Use wget to download the bash installer Now that the bash installer (.sh file) link is stored on the clipboard, use wget to download the
>    installer script. In a terminal, cd into the home directory and make a
>    new directory called tmp. cd into tmp and use wget to download the
>    installer. Although the installer is a bash script, it is still quite
>    large and the download will not be immediate (Note the link below
>    includes . the specific release depends on when you download
>    the installer).

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3<release>.sh
```

> 5. Run the bash script to install Anaconda3 With the bash installer script downloaded, run the .sh script to install Anaconda3. Ensure you
>    are in the directory where the installer script downloaded:

```
$ ls
Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

now we can run the installer script with bash.

```
$ bash Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

**update**: tried to install all anaconda-things according the official instruction - went the hard way - on terminal: see these docs: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

a quick walktrough through the steps ended up in fully-fledged installation of Anaconda3

**next steps** are shown here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/

**Linux**: Open a terminal window and type anaconda-navigator.

voila - now Anaconda3 starts...

**conclusio**: all is fine now..

have a great day  ;)